# Use template to select which templatized member function is called

Tags: c++, templates, member-functions

In my real code I am parsing a series of bytes that are consecutive messages. An integer in a message header determines what is the appropriate way to interpret the bytes

To simplify for SO assume the following:

- `1` means use `struct MsgA`
- `2` means use `struct MsgB`
- `3` means use `struct MsgC`
- Any other value is invalid

Also for SO assume that a class, `NamePrinter` is responsible for:

- Receiving a type (one of `MsgA`, `MsgB`, or `MsgC`)
- Instantiating that type
- Calling some methods of that type (just one method in the code below for the
  sake of example)

I know how to write code for this. I also know how to switch out `NamePrinter` with another class that also performs actions on messages. What I do not do not know how to do is chose which member function of `NamePrinter` (or another class) to call in a more general case

```
#include <iostream>

// Some made up "message" structs
struct MsgA final {
    static constexpr int getId() { return 1; }
    const char* getName() const { return "MsgA"; }
    const char* getSomethingElse() const { return "SomethingElseA"; }
};
struct MsgB final {
    static constexpr int getId() { return 2; }
    const char* getName() const { return "MsgB"; }
    const char* getSomethingElse() const { return "SomethingElseB"; }
};
struct MsgC final {
    static constexpr int getId() { return 3; }
    const char* getName() const { return "MsgC"; }
    const char* getSomethingElse() const { return "SomethingElseC"; }
};

// A class that creates a "message" and performs and action on it
class NamePrinter final {
public:
    template <class T>
    void onMsgPrintName() const {
        T t;
        std::cout << t.getName() << std::endl;
    }

    template <class T>
    void onMsgPrintSomethingElse() const {
        T t;
        std::cout << t.getSomethingElse() << std::endl;
    }
};

// A function that can convert an integer into a "message" at compile time but
// is hardcoded to call onMsgPrintName
template <class T>
void intToPrintName(const T& a_caller, const int a_id) {
    switch (a_id) {
    case MsgA::getId(): a_caller.template onMsgPrintName<MsgA>(); break;
    case MsgB::getId(): a_caller.template onMsgPrintName<MsgB>(); break;
    case MsgC::getId(): a_caller.template onMsgPrintName<MsgC>(); break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Runtime error" << std::endl;
    }
}

// This is invalid but tries to convey that onMsgPrintName has been replaced
// with a template
//template <class F, class T>
//void intToFunc(const T& a_caller, const int a_id) {
//    switch (a_id) {
//    case MsgA::getId(): a_caller.template F<MsgA>(); break;
//    case MsgB::getId(): a_caller.template F<MsgB>(); break;
//    case MsgC::getId(): a_caller.template F<MsgC>(); break;
//    default:
//        std::cout << "Runtime error" << std::endl;
//    }
//}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const NamePrinter np;

    // This will end up calling NamePrinter::onMsgPrintName
    intToPrintName(np, argc);

    // I want something like this that allows me to pick what is called
    //intToFunc<NamePrinter::onMsgPrintName         >(np, argc);
    //intToFunc<NamePrinter::onMsgPrintSomethingElse>(np, argc);

    return 0;
}
```

What I would like to know is if I can replace `onMsgPrintName` inside of `intToPrintName` with an arbitrary member function of my choice. The commented out code shows an attempt to do this which does not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another level of indirection - a wrapper that knows how to call a particular method on any object. Along the lines of

```
class OnMsgPrintNameCaller {
  template <typename Param, typename Obj, typename... Args>
  static auto Call(Obj&& obj, Args&&... args) {
    return std::forward<Obj>(obj).template onMsgPrintName<Param>(
      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};
```

And similar class for `onMsgPrintSomethingElse`. Now pass this as an extra parameter to `intToPrintName`:

```
template <typename MethodCaller, typename T>
void intToPrintName(const T& a_caller, const int a_id) {
    switch (a_id) {
    case MsgA::getId(): MethodCaller::template Call<MsgA>(a_caller); break;
    // ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
intToPrintName<OnMsgPrintNameCaller>(np, argc);
```

Comment: Looks like i just need one class (such as `OnMsgPrintNameCaller`) per member function that I care about calling since it still calls `onMsgPrintName` inside `Call`. That works though, much better than having a `switch` function for each member function that I care about

Comment: If you are not allergic to macros, you can write one stamping out `F##Caller` definitions. They are all cookie-cutter.

Comment: I am downright anaphylactic, ha ha. Most of my classes would only have one member function per message type, writing them out is easy enough